# c++: Unhandled exception at 0x57B4B2CE (msvcr120d.dll) in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDC8

Tags: c, debugging, pointers

I am getting this error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x57B4B2CE (msvcr120d.dll) in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDC8
```

and it happens in this part of the code:

```
void Print_Function(char * output_file)
{
    f = 0;
    f = fopen(output_file,"w");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < count_total ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < sizes[i] ; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0 ; k < rules[i][j]->sizes_elements ; k++)
                if (k < rules[i][j]->sizes_elements - 1) fprintf(f,"%i ", elements[rules[i][j]->elements[k]]);
                else fprintf(f,"%i", elements[rules[i][j]->elements[k]]);

            fprintf(f,":%.3f:%i\n", rules[i][j]->measure_value,rules[i][j]->index);

            free(rules[i][j]->elements); rules[i][j]->elements = 0;
            free(rules[i][j]); rules[i][j] = 0;
        }

        free(rules[i]); rules[i] = 0;
    }

    fclose(f); f = 0;

    free(rules); rules = 0;
    free(size_rules); size_rules = 0;
    free(elements); elements = 0;
}
```

the exception launches in this part of the code specifically

```
free(rules[i]); rules[i] = 0;
```

after the first iteration of the outer loop, is the previous free doing something i am not noticing and not like im expecting it to be?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `i`?  Has it gone out of bounds?

Comment: Though this is tagged C++, it looks like C to me.

Comment: `Any help appreciated.`  You want any help?  Rewrite this using `std::vector` and stop the malloc/free insanity.

Comment: This is C (no C++) without any malloc but multiple free - bad code!

Comment: An output function that deallocates the things it outputs is ... surprising. In some places, a reason to be looking for a new job.

Comment: `count_total`  What is this value?  Where, how, and when did you call `malloc` for all this dynamicall allocated memory?

Comment: @molbdnilo I was going to say the same thing.  Why isn't there a nice, clean, separate function to deallocate the memory, instead of shoehorning all of those calls to `free` in the middle of a print function?

Comment: i checked the availability of sizes[i] for > 0 to avoid the free call. I do realize the malloc/free insanity, this is scientific 5 year old code im stuck tinkering with, and with no time to rewrite anything, thank u one more time.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio uses several fake addresses as indicators of the state of memory:

- `0x00000000` : nullptr or NULL
- `0xFEEEFEEE` : delete has been called
- `0xCDCDCDCD` : Memory was created but not initialized.